# how to create configurable products in category list of magento?

Tags: magento

how to create configurable products in category list of magento?
I want to list down a combo box in category list of all products where user can select different sizes or weight?

Note---I want to create configurable items in category pages not in quick view

Example-

http://bigbasket.com/cl/grocery-staples/?nc=nb&sid=mfjP3oWiY2OjMzgxom1kA6FjAaJwZwGiYW_C

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you

ADDING CONFIGURABLE PRODUCT OPTIONS TO CATEGORY LIST IN MAGENTO

refer : http://www.catgento.com/adding-configurable-product-options-to-category-list-in-magento/